# JavaFX hardware acceleration on intel 965

Tags: javafx, intel, hardware-acceleration

I wanted some decent graphics performance for my app.
But the problem is, my graphics card is a bit old and java fx doesn't seem to support it.

i tried setting a few environment variables like 
set J2D_TRACE_LEVEL=4
set J2D_D3D_NO_HWCHECK=true

but that didn't help.

Here is what i get if I use -Dprism.verbose=true option to see what is going on

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization failed
Adapter validation failed for all adapters
Device "Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1)     initialization failed : 
WARNING: Unsupported video adapter found, device disabled
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline     com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
```

How can I get some javafx to leverage my graphics card leverage so that the performance is better?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prism.forceGPU=true` as a command line parameter. It disables adapter support checking.